# Create a "pie element" with RasterX package using AddArc

Tags: go

I'm working on a chart widget for Fyne, I use `rasterx` package (https://github.com/srwiley/rasterx) and it works well. But I spent hours to try to make a circle arc (to create a pie chart elements) without success.

Let's take this starting point:

```golang
cx, cy := float64(w/2.0), float64(h/2.0)
r := float64(w / 3.0)
angle := 45.0
rot := angle * math.Pi / 180.0
```

I take the `AddArc` function at https://github.com/srwiley/rasterx/blob/master/shapes.go#L99 to understand the principle and do:

```golang
points := []float64{r, r, angle, 1, 0, px, py}

stroker.Start(rasterx.ToFixedP(px, py))
rasterx.AddArc(points, cx, cy, px, py, stroker)
stroker.Stop(false)
stroker.Draw()
```

The result is a circle, not an arc.

As the `rasterx` package is based on SVG 2.0 spec, maybe I miss something. Can you please give me a hand to show me how to create a "pie chart element" for a given angle?

Thanks a lot.

PS: I should not use other package than `rasterx`, please do not tell me to use another one.

Comment: Can you share some screenshots or a link with the actual code to have a better understanding of what's wrong or what's not working correctly?

Comment: I will edit this in 1 hour. But you can see the issue I've opened in the GitHub repository.

Comment: It is not clear what `px` and `py` are, but I suspect that  having the same value in the  `points` as passed in to `AddArc` may relate - that is what they do in the `AddEllipse` function, which is desiring a completed 360degs

Comment: And that was exactly what I missed. I used the same vars so that makes a complete rotation. GG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The px, py in `points` needs to be different to the ones passed to `AddArc`. This works for me:

```
        angle := 45.0
        rot1 := angle * math.Pi / 180.0
        rot2 := (angle - 90) * math.Pi / 180.0

        p1x := cx + r*math.Cos(rot1)
        p1y := cy + r*math.Sin(rot1)
        p2x := cx + r*math.Cos(rot2)
        p2y := cy + r*math.Sin(rot2)

        points := []float64{r, r, angle, 1, 0, p2x, p2y}

...

        stroker.Start(rasterx.ToFixedP(p1x, p1y))
        rasterx.AddArc(points, cx, cy, p1x, p1y, stroker)
```

[image]

Comment: My god I didn't see this... Maybe I was tired. Big thanks ! You're a genius 

Answer (score 0):

It’s just a guess but doesn’t the `AddArc` want the radian angle instead of degrees?

Comment: Actually, whatever the angle, the result is the same. I tried degree and rad... No changes 

Comment: Ah yes, I see they do the translation internally for some reason.

Comment: That was the point. Your solution works.